# htaccess rule without noticable redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

i have the following redirect rule

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^$ /folder/
```

basically my index.html file is in folder.html and instead of copy and pasting the index.html file from /folder/ i was trying to use the rule above to request the file and output the file as mysite.com but instead it is redirecting to mysite.com/folder/index.html. I assume this is possible to do as frameworks use the rewrite rule and this doesn't redirect the browser. Can anyone advise on what i am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the the only rule OR you other rules? Is there any .htaccess in `/folder/` also?

Comment: there is a htaccess file in folder but the only rule in the root .htaccess file is the one above

Comment: In that case provide the content of `/folder/.htaccess` also

Comment: @anubhava sorry just seen that the .htaccess file in /folder/ is empty

Comment: Ok change above rule to: `RewriteRule ^$ /folder/ [L]` and delete `/folder/.htaccess`

Comment: Are you sure there's nothing in index.html that is causing the redirect? Is there another index file in `/folder/`?

Comment: @JonLin basically there is noting in the root other then the .htaccess file and there was an empty .htaccess file in /folder/ basically the root .htaccess file was to redirect the / to /folder/index.html however the above rule and anubhava 's rule redirect to /folder/index.html rather then just leaving the page at mysite.com

Comment: @JonLin Your right was the index page itself. I'll look into this further Thank you for your help

Comment: @LiamSorsby: Try that in a new browser to avoid any caching issue. If that doesn't work then backup `index.html` and create a new `index.html` with just some placeholder text. Test it out and let me know.

Comment: @anubhava i moved the index.html to index1.html and created a new index.html page with the word test in it. Testing the htaccess file with the word test in it worked fine. and didn't rewrite the url but the index1.html page did as soon as i moved it back to index.html

Comment: Well that proves that redirect is happening because of some Javascript or `META refresh` in your `index.html` Try to find that out and fix it.